# Firefox cannot access internet with mobile data (but does with Wi-Fi). Chrome works with both

Tags: mobile-network, android-12, miui-13, poco-3

My phone is a Xiaomi Poco X3 pro, running Android 12 (QKQ1), and it says it has MIUI Global 13.0.4 stable. Firefox is version 118.1.1. With Firefox, I am able to access the internet through Wi-Fi, but not using mobile data. With Chrome, both work.

[image]

I have checked the permissions (Wi-Fi and mobile data are allowed), and even deleted and re-installed Firefox, and also reset the AP settings associated with my SIM card. Nothing helped.

I should say that in the past no such problems had occurred, but I do not know when exactly this problem started to occur.

Another observation is (and I am not sure whether that could be related) that some apps seem to sometimes lose network connectivity until I restart them. For example, I have a public transport app to search for connections and buy tickets, which sometimes hangs until I remove it from memory and restart it. This problem seems not to occur with other people using the same app at the same time and place (but on another phone).

What else can I check to solve this problem?

Comment: AFAIK, Firefox has its own certificate store, and looks like the screenshot shows that it failed to connect to the website securely. Not sure if it's due to [DNS hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking) by the cell provider.

Comment: You can check which DNS mode is configured in Firefox: [How do I enable DNS over HTTPS on Firefox for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214574/2241)

Answer (score 3):

I feel really stupid, but it seems for some reason my mobile data AP was configured with a proxy (I did not do that, so this must somehow have happened automatically). Since I removed the proxy, everything works.